# In access, query from form won't show records

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am creating a database that collects information about employers.

I am trying to create a form that will open a parameter query. The form has a combo box listing employers, and then a command button for search and cancel. When the user makes their selection from the combo box and clicks the search button in the form, I want access to open up a query based on the selection. I did something similar to this with a query that pulled from multiple tables, and experienced a similar problem that was solved by changing the JOINs. This time the query is only pulling from one table.

Here is the SQL for the query

```
SELECT
    [Employer Contact].Employer, [Employer Contact].Supervisor,
    [Employer Contact].[Supervisor Phone], [Employer Contact].[Supervisor Email],
    [Employer Contact].Street, [Employer Contact].Town, [Employer Contact].Zip,
    [Employer Contact].Region
FROM
    [Employer Contact]
WHERE
    ((([Employer Contact].Employer)=[Forms]![Edit Employer Contact Info]![cboContactSearch]));
```

And here is the VBA for the form

```
Private Sub cmdContactSearch_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Employer Contact Query", acViewNormal
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Edit Employer Contact Info"
End Sub
```

How do I set this up so that when the user clicks search, the query opens with the selected record?

Comment: Make sure the bound column of the combobox contains the same kind of information as the column you are filtering. E.g. if the combobox contains a contact name but the column contains a contact ID, then the filter will not work.

Comment: They should be the same, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Since the form you are closing contains the information for the filter, closing it might be a problem. Try make it invisible instead.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: `Me.Visible = False`.

Comment: If you open the query `Employer Contact Query` manually whilst the form remains open with something selected in the combo box control, does it return the appropriate results? If you evaluate `?[Forms]![Edit Employer Contact Info]![cboContactSearch]` in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) of the VBE, does it return the data that you would expect to use to filter the query?